# Search object array for specific value and return multiple results

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to find all objects in multiple arrays with a specific value, returning another value of this image of all matching objects.

I'll try to make it a bit clearer with an example. I'm searching for every `target` with the value `find-me` and get the `source` value returned.
Some arrays have matching objects, some may not have. The result array should have unique values.

```
const deps = {
  "something": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "foo",
      "target": "bar"
    },
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "return-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "anything": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "and-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "no-match": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "foo",
      "target": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

So for this example, the result should be

```
['return-me', 'and-me']
```

I tried this:

```
const search = 'find-me'
const sources = Object
  .values(deps)
  .flat()
  .find(el => el.target === search)
  .map(el => el.source)
```

But of course this can't work, as `find` will give me only one result (which is an object). How do I get all results instead of first matching object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Array.find`, you need to use `Array.filter` to get the matched results.

```js
const deps = {
  "something": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "foo",
      "target": "bar"
    },
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "return-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "anything": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "and-me",
      "target": "find-me"
    }
  ],
  "no-match": [
    {
      "type": "static",
      "source": "foo",
      "target": "bar"
    }
  ]
};

const result = Object.values(deps)
  .flat()
  .filter(({ target }) => target === 'find-me')
  .map(({ source }) => source);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Array.find()` with `Array.filter()` that can return multiple results:

```js
const deps = {"something":[{"type":"static","source":"foo","target":"bar"},{"type":"static","source":"return-me","target":"find-me"}],"anything":[{"type":"static","source":"and-me","target":"find-me"}],"no-match":[{"type":"static","source":"foo","target":"bar"}]}

const search = 'find-me'
const sources = Object
  .values(deps)
  .flat()
  .filter(el => el.target === search)
  .map(el => el.source)
  
console.log(sources)
```